# can't fill an array using a file

Tags: c++, arrays, file

Good morning all.

I'm starting to learn c++ and i'm trying to make a prog that converts from one currency to another.

I made a text file "currency.txt" where i have all currencies, one after another, each with 4 lines:

Country, Currency description, Currency code, Exchange rate.

So far i made the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct currency {
    string country;
    string coin;
    string code;
    double rate;
};

int count_lines ( ifstream &myfile ){
    string line;
    int lines = 0;

    if ( myfile.is_open() ){

        while ( getline( myfile, line ) ){
            ++lines;

        }
    } else cout << "error";

    myfile.seekg (0, ios::beg);

    return lines;
}

void read_coins ( currency coins[], ifstream &myfile, int lines) {

    string line;

    if ( myfile.is_open() ){

        for ( int n=0; n<lines; n++){

            getline( myfile, line );
            coins[n].country = line;
            getline( myfile, line );
            coins[n].coin = line;
            getline( myfile, line );
            coins[n].code = line;
            getline( myfile, line );
            stringstream(line) >> coins[n].rate;
         }

    } else cout << "error";

    myfile.seekg (0, ios::beg);

}

int main(){

    ifstream myfile ( "currency.txt" );
    int lines;

    lines = count_lines ( myfile )/4;
    currency coins [lines];

    read_coins (coins, myfile, lines);

    for (int n=0; n<lines; n++){
        cout << coins[n].country << '\t';
        cout << coins[n].coin << '\t';
        cout << coins[n].code << '\t';
        cout << coins[n].rate << endl;
    }

    myfile.close ();

    return 0;
}
```

But it's just not working. If i open the file inside all of the functions it works, but not like this.
I know there must be a problem for sure but i just can't figure it ou yet.

And i have another problem: the exchage rates have 10 decimal digits, but when i put it in my coins[n].rate, it comes only with 5 ou 6 decimal digits. Is there anyway to get all 10?

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks

Comment: could you elaborate exactly what not working.

Comment: You read until the end of file, then seek to the beginning but don't clear the stream status, so I suspect the end-of-file flag is still set.  Try calling `myfile.clear()` too before, immediately before or after `seekg`.  `#include <iomanip>` then use `std::setprecision` to request a specific precision in displaying floating point output.

Comment: thanks @TonyD. That was the problem indeed! molbdnilo gave that explanation also!

Comment: Why don't you debug your code instead of asking us?

Comment: @sashoalm: am i bothering? i'm sorry if so. If you see the very beginning of my post i clearly say that i'm starting to learn. I'm really sorry if i don't know yet how to do everything, as debuging for instance. but don't worry. i'll learn.

Comment: @Disgrace There's nothing wrong with being newbie, but we're inundated with questions like that. See http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @sashoalm i thought that this was a place where we could put our questions, newbie or not. i can imagine that there are many questions like this. perhaps i was wrong about the purpose of this site and i need to find another to put my questions (cause they will be plenty). nevertheless thats why there is a system of voting here and my question already has -1. But i can assure you that i did research and, believe it or not, didn't find this issue concerning seekg and c++11. i don't question without researching, because i believe that if i relly allways on other people then i'll never learn.

Comment: @Disgrace It's ok to post newbie questions, so long as they are not essentially "Fix my code". See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions

Comment: @sashoalm. Ok. i understood. I won't question here more like this and go ask somewhere else. But btw, i have all warnigs on, my code compiled successfully with no errors. of course i didn't have a rubber ducky so maybe that was the problem.

Comment: @Disgrace Do you know what debugging means? Cause your "it compiles" comment made me wonder about that. If not, see this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vDKXIq_9A.

Comment: @sashoalm: i know what debugging means. although it compiled without errors there was, clearly an error in my code (in this case by omission) that made it run but didn't give the result i was expecting. i'm sure that if i knew how to work well with the debugger in code blocks i would surely find out that the end-of-file flag was still on. but i'm still working on learning how to use it. but hey, as it says here when i'm writing this, we should avoid extended discussions in comments so, be cool. And thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using C++11, `seekg` doesn't reset the end-of-file state of the file.

Add `myfile.clear()` before seeking to the beginning.

The output of floating point numbers depends on the current precision of the stream.
The default is six (6).

Add

```
 #include <iomanip>
```

and

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(10);
```

before output.
(But remember that floating-point is inexact in itself, so you won't necessarily get exactly the same number as in the file - only the closest one possible.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! i'm using code blocks but don't know what is the version of c++. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: it worked just fine!!! didn't know that seekg doesn't reset the end-of-file flag. thanks a lot